# One component with two instances of the same services

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a query builder service, and I would like to use it twice in a component. Can this be done? I have tried injecting the service twice but this doesn't seem to work, as the services just reference one another as seen here:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-users',
  templateUrl: './manage-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-users.component.scss'],
  providers: [UserManagementQueryBuilderProvider]
})
export class ManageUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  public constructor(
    private readonly queryBuilder: QueryBuilderService,
    private readonly qb: QueryBuilderService
  ) { }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.queryBuilder.table('users');
    console.log(this.qb['_table']); // Outputs "users"; expecting an empty string.
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this is because of how my provider is setup (aka, the multi option) or not but it looks like this:

```js
export const UserManagementQueryBuilderProvider: Provider = {
  useFactory: (httpClient: HttpClient) => new QueryBuilderService(httpClient)
    .connection(environment.USER_MANAGEMENT_API),
  provide: QueryBuilderService,
  deps: [HttpClient],
  multi: false
};
```

If I set `multi` to `true`, I get an error saying that table is not a function.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.queryBuilder.table is not a function

The `QueryBuilderService` then looks like this:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export abstract class GraphQLClientService {
  public constructor(
    private readonly httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }
}


@Injectable()
export class QueryBuilderService extends GraphQLClientService { }
```

Comment: It seems you’re overthinking this? You don’t need a service at all and you don’t need (or even want) to DI it. You can make a class that you can create yourself inside your component using new myBuilder and you’re done..?

Comment: The querybuilder class injects `HttpClient` to make http requests. I have updated the question to include this information.

Comment: It’s unclear what you want and why you want it I’m afraid. A DI’t angular service is by definition a singleton. However, you can create a factory function inside your service that returns new instances of whatever you want right..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Alias providers**:
>
> The `useExisting` provider key lets you map one token to another. In effect, the first token is an alias for the service associated with the second token, creating two ways to access the same service object. ([Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action))

Consider providing two `InjectionToken`s with `UseExisting` set to `false`, this way two different instances of `QueryBuilderService` will be injected,  as demonstrated below:

```
import { Component, InjectionToken, Inject } from '@angular/core';

const QueryBuilder1 = new InjectionToken("QB1")
const QueryBuilder2 = new InjectionToken("QB2")

@Component({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: QueryBuilder1,
      useClass: QueryBuilderService,
      useExisting: false
    },
    {
      provide: QueryBuilder2,
      useClass: QueryBuilderService,
      useExisting: false
    }
  ]
})
export class ManageUsersComponent {

  public constructor(
    @Inject(QueryBuilder1) private queryBuilder1: QueryBuilderService,
    @Inject(QueryBuilder2) private queryBuilder2: QueryBuilderService
  ) { }

}
```